# Adding Tab Layout (using fragments) to an already made app (Push Notifications)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a beginner on Android. I made an android app that handles push notifications through the GCM service and now I need to add more capabilities to the app and so I thought that tabs would be the perfect thing. Like I said I have the push notifications app working and also another app that has tabs layout with swipeable view working, but now I need to merge them, that's where I'm lost.

How should I do it? I tried adding the code of the mainactivity of the Tabs app to the other one and also adding the fragments but that didn't work.

Maybe I just need to paste the code of the Push app in one of the new fragments(?)

This is what I did (this is part of the app):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPager_Adapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Login Screen", "Estado de Sensores", "Botones" };

public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME_MS = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7;
String SENDER_ID = "171235143158";
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private Context context;
    private String regid;
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

    private EditText txtUser;
    private Button btnRegistrar;

    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

private static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private static final String PROPERTY_EXPIRATION_TIME = "onServerExpirationTimeMs";
private static final String PROPERTY_USER = "user";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPager_Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);       

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs)
    {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) 
        {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
        {
        }

    });


     txtUser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario);
     btnRegistrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);

    btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            context = getApplicationContext();

            //Chequeamos si está instalado Google Play Services
            if(checkPlayServices())
            {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

                    //Obtenemos el Registration ID guardado
                    regid = getRegistrationId(context);

                    //Si no disponemos de Registration ID comenzamos el registro
                    if (regid.equals("")) {
                        TareaRegistroGCM tarea = new TareaRegistroGCM();
                        tarea.execute(txtUser.getText().toString());
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No se ha encontrado Google Play Services.");
            }
        }


    });


}
```

Comment: `...that didn't work` - this is not helpful at all, nobody can guess how your code looks like and why it fails.

Comment: I pasted part of the code now, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should understand for Android is the Intent principle.
Using intentions and BroadcastReceivers you can send your own intents even to wake up "applications".

For example you can set an action string as GCM_RECEIVED and add Extra values if required to handle it.

Start looking here for simple examples of Broadcast concepts,
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: I know what an intent is and what the broadcastreceiver does. That part works fine. What I need now is adding tabs using fragments to the Push app.

Comment: I still not fully understand your question / problem. I'd suggest creating each Tab as Fragment for each for example: 'public class LoginFragment extends Fragment'.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain it better. I followed this tutorial:  [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) to add the Tabs. I created each Tab as a fragment: LoginScreenFragment, ButtonsFragment, StateFragment. I made sort of a template out of that tutorial. Out of this tutorial:  [link](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=4126) I made an app that handles Push notifications using the GCM service. The mainactivity has an OnClickListener event that registers the device in the GCM server.

Comment: Now, can i just add the tabs/fragments to the push app or edit one fragment as the push app?